# How to access each word in the String array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

My program reads in a `file` with the sentence:

> The clock struck one

I put this sentence into a `String` and split the `String` at every white space.

My only question is how to access each word in this `array`? Also, are these words a single string or represented as an `Integer` in its position in the `array`?

```
JFileChooser cho = new JFileChooser();
File file = cho.getSelectedFile();
String string = readFile(file);

for(int i = 1; i <= string.length(); i++)
{
    String [] words = string.split(" ");
    //This is where I'm stuck 
}
```

Comment: Double check the [javadoc for split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)  There's no need to have it in a loop.

Comment: Use `String [] words = string.split(" ");` outside the loop

Answer (score 4):

```
JFileChooser cho = new JFileChooser();
File file = cho.getSelectedFile();
String string = readFile(file);
String [] words = string.split(" "); // split the input and assign to an array

for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) { // loop through the array that was created
    System.out.println(words[i]); // print each String in the array
}
```

Comment: @BigRabbit OP thanked me, the code is self explanatory. This is not a difficult task.

Comment: He thanked you because you did their homework for them, this doesn't benefit the community at all.

Comment: @BigRabbit I am not sure what would require explanation in the two lines of code i changed. He had the right idea he used split like he should have he was just looping through the wrong thing. As follows I did not think this required further comment. But we can sit here and split hairs...

Comment: Just because the OP has an idea of what might be going on, does not mean someone who might stumble across this page looking for a similar solution in the future will.

Comment: @BigRabbit added comments

Answer (score 2):

Split the string and THEN use your loop to go over the array.

```
String[] words = string.split(" ");
for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    //iterate over words array using words[i] as your accessor. 
}
```

Comment: length of array is a property, not a function call.

Comment: Thanks, though I made that edit before you called me out on it :) Too many lists today.

Answer (score 1):

When you split the String into chunks and put them into the array

```
String text = "The clock struck one";
String [] chunks = text.split(" ");
```

They are stored in it and assigned to Integer indexes like:

```
String firstChunk = chunks[0];
```

The content of firstChunk is "The".
If you would like to iterate the array and access the chunks you do like that:

```
for (String chunk : chunks) {
    System.out.println(chunk);
}
```

It's a pretty basic question though. You should research more for stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
String string = "blah1 blah2 blah3";
String[] words = string.split("");
```

In there `words[0]` is blah1, `words[1]` is blah2 and `words[2]` is blah3.
However that does not work with comas or dots.

Answer (score -1):

```
JFileChooser cho = new JFileChooser();
File file = cho.getSelectedFile();
String string = readFile(file);
String [] words = string.split(" ");

for(String word: words){
    System.out.println(word)
}
```

Comment: @BigRabbit He was just confused but has the idea. Code is self explanatory but if you have some problems understanding it I can explain it to you.

Comment: See my comments on Code Whisperers answer for my reasoning.

Comment: Everything doesn't require 10 lines of explanation. If someone doesn't understand what has been done in the code then they can ask. That's what the community is all about.

Comment: @SandeepPoonia some of the idea is to try and prevent further questioning.

Comment: So you want someone 6 months from now to comment on your question and ask for an explanation, and wait for who knows how long to get a reply, or even get a reply at all? If anything that hinders the community, not help it.

Comment: So you want to say after 6 months from now on there will be no one to answer a question. If I'm not available others are.

Comment: If you want to prevent further questioning or think that after 6 months there may come some question on some one's reply, put a comment over there asking for some explanation or anything that you think might be helpful to others.

Comment: Giving a negative rating and saying no explanation LOL, won't help others either.

Comment: _If you want to prevent further questioning or think that after 6 months there may come some question on some one's reply, put a comment over there asking for some explanation or anything that you think might be helpful to others_  -   I did exactly that, glad you finally understand.